# How to bend an Image in java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, bufferedimage, affinetransform

Is there any way to bend a `BufferedImage` in Java?

I thought that if I crop the image into smaller pieces and rotate them then I would essentially bend the image, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is the method I created:

```
/**
 * This is a recursive method that will accept an image the point where the bending will start and the point where the bending will end, as well as the angle of bending
 * 
 * @param original:the original image
 * @param startingPoint: the point where the bending should start
 * @param endingPoint: the point where the bending should end
 * @param radiands: the angle
 * @return the bent image
 */
public static BufferedImage getBentImage(BufferedImage original, int startingPoint, int endingPoint, double radians) {
    if (startingPoint >= endingPoint)
        return original;

    int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;
    int width = original.getWidth();
    int height = original.getHeight();

    BufferedImage crop = original.getSubimage(0, 0, startingPoint, height);
    BufferedImage crop0 = original.getSubimage(startingPoint, 0, width - startingPoint, height);
    BufferedImage bendCrop = new BufferedImage(width, height, type);
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, type);

    AffineTransform rotation = new AffineTransform();
    rotation.translate(0, 0);
    rotation.rotate(radians);

    Graphics2D g = bendCrop.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(crop0, rotation, null);
    g.dispose();

    g = image.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(crop, 0, 0, null);
    g.drawImage(bendCrop, startingPoint, 0, null);
    g.dispose();

    return getBentImage(image, startingPoint + 1, endingPoint, radians);
}
```

This is the original Image:

[image: original Image]

And this is the result of this `getBentImage(image, 200, 220, Math.toRadians(1))`:

[image: result]

I was expecting something closer to:

[image: expected result]

Any ideas on how to actually implement a `getBentImage()` method?

Comment: It's unclear what you actually mean by "bend". Please provide a precise definition of the transformation you are trying to apply.

Comment: @AndyTurner don't they images below explain it?

Comment: No, that's why I asked. What are the parameters of the deformation? What do the starting point, ending point and radians parameters mean? For example, you pass in 1 radian as the parameter, but nothing has rotated by 57 degrees. What would it look like if you "bent" a rectangular grid?

Comment: @AndyTurner starting point is the x coordinate of the image that where it will start to curve and ending point is where  the curving will stop. radiands are the radiands of the curve

Comment: Add to your expected image drawing the parameters of the method so we can see what is what.

Comment: @user1803551 That is an image i made to demonstrate what it should look like, if the program had made i wouldn't have an issue.

Comment: Obviously, now add to that image the depiction of the method parameters. *Show* us what are the starting, ending and radian values. Just like you do with geometry homework.

Comment: @user1803551 Something like `getBentImage(image, 200, 270, Math.toRadians(1))`, not sure about radiands, i just did a random bending

Comment: No, *draw the parameters on the image*, **show** us what they represent *on the image*.

Comment: @user1803551 ok i fixed the image

Comment: Aha, good. So for `getBentImage(image, s, e, Math.toRadians(t))` there is a `t` degrees rotation over the distance from `s` to `e`, yes? And before `s` and after `e` the rectangle is straight?

Comment: I think you need to define better what is a bend for you, it's more related to what algorithm to choose instead of how to implement it. What you usually do is have a function to convert coordinates from original system to the new bended system and redraw the specific space into the new space.

Comment: @user1803551 Correct. Also the rectangle after e is also straight, but no longer parallel to the x-axis

Comment: @nickzoum Then you need really 3 algorithms, one that is a 1:1 equivalence (for the first part), the middle (which change the space corrdinates and you need to investigate more about it) and third part which only rotate the remaining image.

Comment: @PhoneixS i have implemented all in one method, but i suppose it would be better to have 3 seperate, since there is no point in redoing the same thing without a reason. As far as the space coordinates go, i was aware of that, but was not sure how to fix it at the time, therefore i just added an extra padding to the image during testing.

Comment: @nickzoum The problem is you can't do it with fragments (or you get what you got) you need to do it pixel by pixel. Something like `for(pixel : pixels) { newCoord = transformCoor(pixel.x, pixel.y); result[newCoord.x][newCoord.y] = pixel.color; }` where `transformCoor(x,y)` is what bend the space.

Comment: And this is if you don't have into account smooth algorithm or interpolations.

Comment: And for the transform function, you can think in something like x is converted to an angle (and depends on the distance to the center) and y is converted to the radio of the new point respect to the center of the bend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, a simple approach is to divide the image into 3 parts:

1. Identical to the original.
2. Bent according to the bending transformation.
3. Constant diagonal continuation.

Here is a quick and a bit messy example that shows the original shape and the resulting shape below it. I just used a label icon for the images instead of doing custom painting. (Also I didn't adhere to the Java naming conventions with `final` variables because it's math and not typical coding.)

Since there are quite a few variables in the calculation code, I added a sketch at the end that shows what the variables represent.

[image]

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

    static BufferedImage image;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("img.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {

        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 10));
        BufferedImage img2 = transform(15, 100, 300);

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        label1.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
        label1.setOpaque(true);
        label1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        add(label1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img2));
        label2.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
        label2.setOpaque(true);
        label2.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        add(label2);

        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    static BufferedImage transform(int t, int x1, int x2) {

        final double TH = Math.toRadians(t);
        final int D = x2 - x1;
        final int W = image.getWidth();
        final int H = image.getHeight();

        final int dD = (int) (D / (2 * TH) * Math.sin(2 * TH));
        final int dH = (int) (D / TH * Math.pow(Math.sin(TH), 2));
        final int pH = (int) ((W - x2) * Math.tan(2 * TH));

        final int width = W - (D - dD);
        final int height = (int) (H + dH + pH);

        System.out.println(W + " " + H + " -> " + width + " " + height);

        BufferedImage img2 = new BufferedImage(width, height, image.getType());

        for (int x = 0; x < x1; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < H; y++) {
                int rgb = image.getRGB(x, y);
                img2.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
            }
        }

        for (int x = x1; x < x2; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < H; y++) {
                int rgb = image.getRGB(x, y);
                int dx = (int) (D / (2 * TH) * Math.sin(2 * (x-x1) * TH / D));
                int dy = (int) (D / TH * Math.pow(Math.sin((x-x1) * TH / D), 2));
                img2.setRGB(x1 + dx, y + dy, rgb);
            }
        }

        for (int x = x2; x < W; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < H; y++) {
                int rgb = image.getRGB(x, y);
                int dp = (int) ((x - x2) * Math.tan(2 * TH));
                img2.setRGB(x - (D - dD), y + dH + dp, rgb);
            }
        }

        return img2;
    }
}
```

[image]

As for the calculations, I'll leave it for you as homework; it's just geometry/trigonometry which belongs on Math.SE more than on SO. If you can't figure it out I'll give you a direction.

Note that this method might not be fast at all and could certainly be optimized, I'll leave that to you also. Oh, and rounding `double`s to `int`s carelessly, so the result is not pixel-perfect.

Comment: @RavipatiPraveen Don't know what that means. Ask a new question.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know what you mean by bending but essentially you have a rectangle and you break one piece of it and rotate it:

so the algorithm is as follows:

```
rotate line(x, 0, width-1, 0)
rotate line(x, height-1, width-1, height-1)
connect the pieces
```

So essentially you are looking for rotate line.

Comment: That does not achieve continuous bending. If you don't understand the question, ask in the comments instead of posting guesses.