# Java Graphics Object Not Updating?

Tags: java, graphics, jframe, paint, repaint

I have written a class, we'll call this DrawCard for this question, to display a playing card drawn from random in my deck class. I have written a graphics object containing info associated with a playing card, suit, value, color etc. I initialize the object in my main method and add it to a JFrame and it displays and draws everything 100% correctly. I then added a toolbar with a button whose action listener is supposed to create a new DrawCard object, remove the first one from the frame and add the new one to the frame. The program compiles and runs just fine but when I click the button it doesn't draw a new card on the frame. It will remove the first one but won't add the new one to the frame, even if I call the repaint method.

Here is the code I have in my main method:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Paying Card");
JButton button = new JButton("Button 1");

  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  int width = 330;
  int height = 500;

  frame.setSize(width, height);


DrawPlayingCard drawCard = new DrawPlayingCard(1, 1,width,height,1, frame);
  JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar("This Tool Bar Does Nothing.");
  toolBar.add(button);
  toolBar.addSeparator();


  Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
  contentPane.add(toolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);


  frame.add(drawCard);
  button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //Execute when button is pressed
            frame.remove(drawCard);
            frame.repaint();
            //method signature: 
            //public DrawPlayingCard(int x, int y, int width, int height, int arcSize, JFrame frame);
            DrawPlayingCard drawCard2 = new DrawPlayingCard(1, 1, width, height, 1, frame);

            System.out.println("Card drawn");

            frame.add(drawCard2);



        }
    });

  frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  frame.setVisible(true);
```

I have tried calling the repaint method on my JFrame in a few different places around the main method and inside my actionlistener with no luck. I have also tried adding my objects in different orders but nothing seems to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have provided all classes written in the past and I was down voted for providing too much code with my question. How would I do this without being down voted and losing rep, as rep is hard to build up here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `actionPerformed` you do your `repaint` before you add the second card. Try adding the second card before repainting, e.g.

```
frame.remove(drawCard);
DrawPlayingCard drawCard 2 = new DrawPlayingCard(1, 1, width, height, 1, frame);
frame.add(drawCard2);
frame.validate(); // this is what needs to be called to actually paint drawCard2
frame.repaint();
```

EDIT: My answer was incomplete. Try calling `frame.validate()` before the repaint. It's required for the frame to know that it needs to paint the new component on repaint. Similar question for reference: [repaint() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853397/repaint-in-java)

Comment: The OP wrote *"I have tried calling the repaint method on my JFrame in a few different places around the main method and inside my actionlistener with no luck"*. Instead of guessing, ask them if they didn't try what you suggest. Did you try it yourself and made sure it works?

Comment: I hadn't tried their full example myself. If I want to give a suggestion or something to try, should I just post a comment? Thanks!

Comment: Generally yes. If your answer is wrong it will be downvoted justifiably. If you think you have an idea but can't be sure, ask for more details from the OP until you have what you need to write a real answer (which doesn't tell them to try, or maybe, or could be...). I did it myself [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38502480/how-to-bend-an-image-in-java) as an example.

Comment: Thanks Davis! I had been staring at this for over an hour trying everything. I didn't know about the frame.validate() method. I have implemented your answer in the exact order you show and that works like a charm. I have also found that it works just fine without a call to the repaint method so I have left that out unless it is for some reason necessary? But it works without so I have left it out.

Comment: Cool. I actually just learned about the validate method trying to figure this one out too. I'm guessing that the when the validate method invalidates the layout, it forces a redraw. According to the docs for validate: Validates this container and all of its subcomponents.

The validate method is used to cause a container to lay out its subcomponents again. It should be invoked when this container's subcomponents are modified (added to or removed from the container, or layout-related information changed) after the container has been displayed.

Comment: @Randy_E and Davis, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097366/java-swing-revalidate-vs-repaint. And Randy, in the future post [mcve]s. It will help everyone including yourself to understand the problem and you would have gotten an answer much sooner.

Comment: Thanks for the link @user1803551!